# Instantiating and destroying GameObject from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I want to instantiate several instances of a prefab into an array each with their own index number but i keep getting the error code "object reference not set to an instance of an object. How can I get rid of this error and how can I destroy individual objects or retrieve the properties of each individual game object in the array?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnEnemy : MonoBehaviour {
private GameObject[] enemy;
public GameObject enemyPrefab;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
enemy[1] = (GameObject)Instantiate (enemyPrefab, new Vector3 (-119, 52, 483), transform.rotation);

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire2")) {
        Destroy (enemy[1]);
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DrUsh mentiones, you need to initialize the array, e.g. like this:

```
void Start()
{
    // initialize array with a size of 5, all elements are empty
    enemy = new GameObject[5];

    // now you can work with this array, e.g. like you line:
    enemy[1] = (GameObject)Instantiate (enemyPrefab, new Vector3 (-119, 52, 483), transform.rotation);
}
```

The downside of using arrays is that you will have a fixed number of elements (5 in my example). If you don't know the exact number of objects you want at max at the same time stored into your array, you are better of using a `List<GameObject>` which can be resized dynamically. This also needs to be initialized by putting `enemy = new List<GameObject>()`.

Also, you probably don't want to access the array/list with hardcoded indices. I don't know if that was just for example and you have a better, automated way to create gameobject-index pairs though.

Answer (score 0):

You have not instantiated the array before you set the value for `enemy[1]`. Also, the index should be 0, not 1, i.e. `enemy[0] =` ... because the index of a C# array starts from 0.

You can instantiate and set using the below.

```
enemy = new[]
{
    (GameObject)Instantiate(enemyPrefab,
        new Vector3 (-119, 52, 483), transform.rotation)
};
```